# C# Winforms datagridview: readonly in combination with allowUserToAddRows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winforms datagridview where the existing rows shouldn't be editable but the new row should be.
So i set the ReadOnly property to true on the grid, but then i still see the new row but can't edit it.
How can i combine these two properties ?

EDIT: just tried to set ReadOnly to true, but still can't edit or add new rows.

```
  conn = new SqlCeConnection();
  conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
  conn.Open();

  daFacturen = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Factuur", conn);
  daFacturen.Fill(dsKlantenBeheer, "tblFactuur");

  daFactuurRegels = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Factuurregel", conn);
  daFactuurRegels.Fill(dsKlantenBeheer, "tblFactuurregel");

  // Relation between customers and orders
  DataRelation relKlantFactuur;
  DataColumn relKlantFactuurcolMaster;
  DataColumn relKlantFactuurcolDetail;
  relKlantFactuurcolMaster = dsKlantenBeheer.Tables["tblKlant"].Columns["ID"];
  relKlantFactuurcolDetail = dsKlantenBeheer.Tables["tblFactuur"].Columns["KlantID"];
  relKlantFactuur = new DataRelation("RelKlantFactuur", relKlantFactuurcolMaster, relKlantFactuurcolDetail);
  dsKlantenBeheer.Relations.Add(relKlantFactuur);

DataRelation relFactFactregel;
DataColumn relFactFactregelcolMaster;
DataColumn relFactFactregelcolDetail;
relFactFactregelcolMaster = dsKlantenBeheer.Tables["tblFactuur"].Columns["ID"];
relFactFactregelcolDetail = dsKlantenBeheer.Tables["tblFactuurregel"].Columns["FactuurID"];
relFactFactregel = new DataRelation("relFactFactregel", relFactFactregelcolMaster, relFactFactregelcolDetail);
dsKlantenBeheer.Relations.Add(relFactFactregel);

DataViewManager dsView = dsKlantenBeheer.DefaultViewManager;
dsView.DataViewSettings["tblKlant"].RowFilter = "Status = 0 or Status is null";
dsView.DataViewSettings["tblKlant"].Sort = "Naam, Voornaam";

// Grid Databinding 
dgvFacturen.DataSource = dsView;
dgvFacturen.DataMember = "tblKlant.relKlantFactuur";
dgvFacturen.ReadOnly = true;
dgvFacturen.allowUserToAddRows = true;
```

Comment: What is expected after you have committed the new row ? Have you tried using `AllowNew=true;` ?

Comment: allowUserToAddRows is true, where is this AllowNew property to be found ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.allownew.aspx

Comment: if you read the remarks section for `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows`, it says - `If the DataGridView is bound to data, the user is allowed to add rows if both this property and the data source's IBindingList.AllowNew property are set to true.`

Comment: i don't have or use a bindingsource, hoped to avoid that and keep it as simple as possible

Comment: Then please post some code which you have written.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think it was necessary but it seems to be more complicated si i did, can someone show me how to implement this in combination wit a DatabindingSource with the IBindingList.AllowNew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `ReadOnly` for row/cells only, not for whole grid:

```
var row = dataGridView1.Rows[0];
row.ReadOnly = true; //whole row can't be edited
```

or

```
var row = dataGridView1.Rows[0];
row.Cells[0].ReadOnly = true; //only first cell is not editable
```

When `DataGridView` is `ReadOnly` then you can't edit, add, delete any row/cell in grid.

Comment: but then i need to iterate all the rows and after adding redo this, i hoped for an easier solution

Comment: @ gzaxx, have made the grid editable by setting readonly to false, but still can't edit or add

Comment: Did you set rows to readonly and while iterating over them you skipped `NewRow`?

Comment: i did set the whole grid readonly to false but still can't edit nor add, must be something with the relationship

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, simply add some custom code to `CellBeginEdit`, like this:

```
    public bool Editable {get;set;}
    int i;
    private void dataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Editable) return;
        if(i == e.RowIndex)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value == null)
                {                        
                    return;
                }
            }
            e.Cancel = true;                
        }
        else if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 != e.RowIndex)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else i = e.RowIndex;            
    }
```

The code above prevent you from re-editing the new row once you input all the values for all the cells in that row. If you want to allow user to edit that new row after committing all the values, the code seems to be much simpler:

```
private void dataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
        if(Editable) return;
        if(e.RowIndex < dataGridView.Rows.Count - 2)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;                
        }
}
```

I've tested and works like a charm. I suppose your new row will have all the cells input with new values.

Comment: thanks King but i just discovered i can't even edit when the grid is set back to editable, must be something with the realtion, will have to fix that first, any suggestion ?

Comment: @peter ah, you mean you want to allow user to edit the grid if `Editable = true`. If so, that's simple.

Comment: @peter how do you set back your grid `editable`? There is not such a property? Do you mean you want to declare some such a flag?

Comment: at King:in designer, if you select your DataGridView you have the property ReasOnly which i set to true but I still can't edit, presumably becuase i use a relation as the source

Comment: @peter if you do so, the DataGridView is of course read only and you can't edit. the behavior you want can't go with ReadOnly = true. So I think you can use some kind of `flag` instead. I'm going to update my code with `flag`

Comment: at king: but i have set the property to false and still can't edit nor add

Comment: @peter If so, I think your `DataSource` has some problem here. You can try my code with a new DataTable... Or simply there is no need to have a DataSource to test my code. Just an Empty DataGridView at first, try adding rows by typing... Again your `DataSource` may be readonly.